# Testing JAX-WS client with EasyMock

Tags: jax-ws, easymock

I have built a java WS client using jaxws-maven-plugin 2.2 that comunicates with a server side.

Now, I am implementing unit tests using EasyMock for testing client side behaviour but I am newbie.

Could anyone say me some tutorials/posts about testing jax-ws mocking server side using EasyMock?.

Thanks!